# DLNA subtitle standard

Tags: dlna

Can anyone explain to me if it is possible for the DLNA standard to pass information on available external subtitles when playing media files (videos) without transcoding the video file?

If possible, then can anyone show me where this is explained in the DLNA standard?

(I'm trying to implement this using platinum library and don't know how to do it or if this is possible)

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the specification, then no, in it there's no such thing as streaming of external subtitles. If I'm not mistaken, that's not what DLNA was built for. I don't have the DLNA specification since you have to pay for it, but from reading around on the Internet and my own experience this seems to be the case.

However, several manufacturers have their own "interpretations" of the specification and for example Samsung's *PC Share Manager* or the *ReadyDLNA* server can stream external subtitles—external in the sense of subtitle files with the same name as the video, but a different extension.

So, possible: yes, definitely. There's no guarantee this will work with all combinations of servers and devices though. I wouldn't rely on it.

Comment: Thanks for the response, do you know where to find the list of "interpretations" for each manufacture? The target render is an LG smart tv.

Comment: No, sorry, I'm afraid this is beyond my knowledge!